# Añadir un dia a un GetValue

Tags: javascript

Tengo este código:

```
<ext:Parameter Name="fin" Value="DTF_FIN.getValue()" Mode="Raw" />
```

y necesito que aparte de recogerlo me añada 1 día esto es posible?

Saludos.

Comment: ¿Podrías dar más contexto de lo que necesitas?

Comment: Ahora mismo coge el dato que le ponemos en una caja. Pues ese GetValue quiero transformarlo para añadirle un dia.